# How to escape slash(/) in URL if there is a param ahead of search text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, routes

**Scenario:**

**URL**: http://www.url.com/search/test10/22/

**Search Term:** test10

**Category id:** 22

But what if i have the search parameter like : `test10/20test`, so for such `search` term the url is like

**URL**: http://www.url.com/search/test10/20test/22

So it is now considering:

**Search Term:** test10

**Category id:** 20test

which is wrong.

How i can write the `constraint` for it such that it will consider

**Search Term:** test10/20test

**Category Id:** 22

My Routes allow two patterns:

1) get 'search/search_key'

2) get 'search/search_key/:id'

with constraints

**search_key**: /.+/,

**id**: /[^0\D][0-9]*/

Comment: Why don't you encode your search term?

Comment: It works perfectly fine when user add `test/20` in search box as it converts it into `test%2020` in the url, but problem exist when user add `test/20` directly in the url

Comment: probably thats why it is good idea to use search query as get parameters `url?q=test/20`

Comment: Why would the user put something in the url?

Comment: first of all getting parameter in this form is not correct, why not as the query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wildcard segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) at your route. For example:

```
get 'search/*search_key/:id', to: 'search#show', constraints: { id: /\d.+/, search_key: /.*/   }
```

At your controller:

```
search_key = params[:search_key]
```

For a url like this `http://www.url.com/search/test10/22/` your `params[:search_key]` would be `test10`

For url such as `http://www.url.com/search/test10/20test/22`, your `params[:search_key]` would be `test10/20test`.

Comment: Got it. But my routes also allow only search term like:
`get 'search/search_key' -> ...`

If i put a constraint for `id` to be only integer still it will treat this product (iPhone/20) differently.

Comment: I'll update my question. Please have a look in some time

Comment: I still did not understand why `iPhone/20` will be treated differently.

Comment: See the update question, i have added routes there. Now the search query is `iPhone/20` which as per the routes, it will match to the 2nd case and treat 20 as Id. Can you explain how `wildcard segment` will work here ?

Comment: With wildcard segment, the last part will be considered as a key, and everything in between `search/` and `:key` will be considered as search_key.

Comment: so if you have `search/iphone/20/21` then `21` will be `id` and `iphone/20` will be `search_key`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96221/discussion-between-ahmad-hamza-and-sadaf2605).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
get 'search/*search_key/:id', to: 'search#show', constraints: { search_key: /.*/, id: /\d+/ }
```

I think, you need to send search query after id like:-

```
get 'search/:id(/:search_key)' => 'search#show', :constraints => { , id: /\d+/, search_key: /.*/}
```